Collision and Second Preimage Resistance for Keyed Sponges?
I was reading the specification for ASCON and I noticed that their claimed security levels for the ASCON hash (derived from the Sponge construction mode used) are as follows:
Let $l$ be the digest size and $c$ be the capacity size. Then, the security claims are:
Collision Resistance: $min(c/2, l/2)$
Second-Preimage Resistance: $min(c/2, l)$
My question is, in the case that a keyed Sponge mode is used (say outer-keyed sponge) and a new variable $k$ (key size) is introduced, do these security claims change?

I guess it depends on your model. I mean, if you have an oracle that allows calculation of the function then I guess that collision resistance would be the same. But that would be  strange model, usually you introduce a key to a hash or sponge to perform authentication. And for authentication key recovery would be of course a bit of an issue, a $k$ of 1 would not be a good idea.

Thank you. Yes, I'm mostly concerned with HMAC side of things. From the literature, I know keyed Sponge provides security min(2^c/2, 2^k) but I did not know whether there are any implications of k on collision and preimage resistance.

I understand, but generally using a hash function that way comes with its own set of cryptographic properties & attack vectors. Say I'm receiving a message that was "signed" with a HMAC. Collision resistance is not a huge topic for MAC after all, as the attacker would still require the key to create the collision and the message is normally either randomized or publicly available. This is why quite often a MAC gets truncated; collision resistance is not top of the list of properties that the user is looking for.

As indicated, if there is an oracle then I would not expect changes as I don't see much of a difference of calculating the hash function yourself against having somebody perform the calculation for you (given a key), but I'm leaving the answering to somebody that can back it up. All this assuming that the hash & MAC constructions are secure of course.

Keying can affect the security because the capacity is often reduced (e.g., 192 bits for a 128-bit security level) for better performance since having a key reduces attacker control. The output might also be shorter like a 128-bit AEAD tag. The other thing is full state absorption should affect the collision resistance since schemes doing that lack commitment from memory so aren't a good idea. You want a MAC to be collision resistant because they're used in scenarios where that property matters.
